# FeatureLayer - won't render

Tags: reactjs, esri, arcgis-js-api

I have a rather simple code that creates a FeatureLayer where I try to add some client side graphic.

```
facilitiesLayer = new FeatureLayer({
        title: 'Facilities layers',
        objectIdField: 'id',
        source: [
          new Graphic({
            geometry: new Point({ longitude: -96.1034353, latitude: 41.5333259 }),
            attributes: {
              id: 1,
            },
          }),
        ],
        renderer: new SimpleRenderer({
          symbol: new SimpleMarkerSymbol({
            size: 32,
            color: '#4652C2',
            outline: {
              color: 'rgba(137,144,215,0.7)',
              width: 2,
            },
          }),
        }),
      });
      mapView.current!.map.add(facilitiesLayer);
```

after I add the layer to the map I immediately see this in console. If I comment out add layer addition, the map is properly displayed, meaning all of the ESRI stuff is created correct.
How do I find where this conversion fails?

using `@arcgis/core 4.18.0`

[image]

Comment: Are all of your constructors in scope? How are you importing SimpleRenderer, SimpleMarkerSymbol, Graphic, etc?

Comment: As described here https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/es-modules/, `import WebMap from '@arcgis/core/WebMap';` and such.

Comment: The feature layer definition seems fine, the problem must be somewhere else. Add more info to the post, like more code, a working example with error if possible.

Comment: here is the full code https://gist.github.com/integral-llc/386d2b0897c6c87072902641bdab1320

Comment: well, I have no idea what's wrong with ES modules, but if I use the esri-loader, https://gist.github.com/integral-llc/61423f24d8197ac99cba1cf01f7ba383, then all works as needed. Somewhat inconvenient having all those Ctors and very testing unfriendly, but it looks like there is no other way :(